# run a powershell 7 file script using session

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

The script below has been running on ps 5 till now. However i must now run it on 7 due to specific file scripts changes
Can any one help me how to call this script PS 7.0

```
$Tenant = 'user'
$TenantPass = ConvertTo-SecureString 'pwd' -AsPlainText -Force
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
$credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Tenant, $TenantPass

$s = New-PSSession -ComputerName 'sv1' -Credential $credential

Invoke-Command -Session $s -Command { 
   & 'C:\file.ps1' -TenantUname $Tenant -newMail '<AD_email/>' -licensa '<CodigoExterno/>' -estado $<isActivar/>
}
Remove-PSSession $s
```

Comment: Are you having trouble running the script in PowerShell 7, or trouble making it connect to a PowerShell7 remoting endpoint when you use `New-PSSession`/`Invoke-Command`?

Comment: Just to spell it out: Given what answer you accepted, the implication is that the only problem was not knowing what PowerShell _CLI_ to use in order to call a script from _outside_ PowerShell (you didn't need to post a specific script's content here). The _Windows PowerShell_ CLI is [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), the one for _PowerShell (Core) 7+_ is  [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need to use

```
pwsh file.ps1
```

instead

```
powershell file.ps1
```